# How to run fixed-effects model on survey data in R?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, survey, fixed-effects-model, plm

I have two periods of panel data and I am trying to see if coefficients change over time. I would like to control for individual-level heterogeneity, but not sure how to do it with a complex design object and svyglm function:

```r
# Libraries
library(survey)

# complex survey design
des <- svydesign(
  ~ secu , # stratum half-sample code
  strata = ~stratum , # std error stratum
  weights = ~wtresp , # weights
  nest = TRUE ,
  data = long
)
```

`secu` is "the stratum half-sample code for analysis of sampling error using the BRR method or approximate 'two-per-stratum' Taylor Series method (Kish and Hess, 1959). Within the SR sampling error strata, the half sample units are created by dividing sample cases into random halves, HALF SAMPLE CODE = 1 and HALF SAMPLE CODE = 2" (taken from here https://hrs.isr.umich.edu/sites/default/files/biblio/surveydesign.pdf).

In the regression below the outcome variable is the retirement status. The regressors are dummy variables for sex, education, race, self-reported health, age, income. In order to see if the effect of these variables becomes stronger in the second period, I include a time dummy variable which equals to 1 if the respondent's interview is from the 2nd time period, (and 0 if from the 1st). I also include dummy variables for month and year when the interview was collected.

```
summary(svyglm(
  retired ~ time*(female + college + factor(race) + age + Rshlt + 
            log(iearn + 1) + factor(month) + factor(year)),
  design = des
))
```

I have tried using `plm()` with weights, but not sure if it is an appropriate method for complex survey samples.

Comment: Hi @pawpaw, welcome to CV. Can you provide some more information about what your variables mean, in the body of your question?

Comment: Can the indivual by considering a secondary sampling unit? Then, they could be accounted for by `svdesign(ids = ~ secu + individual_id)`

Comment: Hi @AlexJ, thank you for your reply. I have added more information about my variables to my question.

Comment: @AlexJ would you mind clarifying - "Can the indivual by considering a secondary sampling unit?"

Comment: In "I would like to control for individual-level heterogeneity," - does this mean you have multiple responses per individual?

Comment: Re secondary sampling unit (SSU) - in survey sampling, the primary sampling unit (PSU) is the first level of clustering, and the secondary sampling unit is the level below that. For example, the PSU could be a household and the SSU a person. We expect that within a cluster, there is some correlation in responses, which is what defining `ids` in the survey design object accounts for when calculating standard errors etc.

Comment: Hi @AlexJ, yes some individuals are observed in both time periods and some only in one (no interview or they are outside of the age range I am interested in).

Comment: In my data primary sampling units are “metropolitan statistical areas, counties or groups of counties”. Secondary sampling units are census blocks or groups of census blocks.

Comment: What's `secu`? The most important thing for getting correct results for is passing the survey design into the `svydesign` object. I would expect `ids = ~ PSU + SSU` or something like that

Comment: And you trying to test if the interaction of `time` and `female`, `college` etc. changes?

Comment: and specifically, what does _I would like to control for individual-level heterogeneity_ mean?

Comment: The reason I put ```ids = ~secu``` because I saw it done this way for this survey data in an example here: https://github.com/bwlewis/usgsd/blob/master/Health%20and%20Retirement%20Study/longitudinal%20RAND%20-%20analysis%20examples.R. Which is probably not the best reason, but I had to start somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to see if the coefficients on the interaction of time and other variables change and are significant. And because I have repeated observations I would like to control for time-invariant heterogeneity across individuals https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_effects_model

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to tag your name above @AlexJ